# Why are literals not const (except strings)?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Literals are, in general, `prvalue`s.
Strings are a special case, defined as an array of `char` (meaning `lvalue`).
This question is specifically about *not string* literals.

Why are non-string literals not `const`?

```
foo(42); // passes foo an `int`, not a `const int`.
```

You can't modify a non-string literal, so doesn't it make sense for it to be `const`?

Comment: Do you have in mind a use case where it would matter?

Comment: Top-level const qualifiers on function arguments are discarded anyway (ie, `void foo(const int)` is identical to `void foo(int)`). So what difference would it make?

Comment: Not a duplicate - the title specifically excludes string literals, so a question about string literals literally cannot be a duplicate.

Comment: I *really* can't think of a way for this to make a difference, except for literally writing `decltype(42)`. Can you elaborate on what it would bring?

Comment: @Angew consider a template accepting a reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076660/template-accepts-const-but-not-literal/52076811#52076811

Comment: Historical accident. In C, what you can and cannot modify was determined purely by the value category of the thing in question (lvalues are modifiable, rvalues are not), with a caveat that modifying a string literal (an lvalue) is UB, which is a typesystem wart. So when C++ tried to fix this, it added `const` to the type of string literals to make them statically non-modifiable. Other literals were statically non-modifiable to begin with, so no one felt there's a need to make them `const`.

Comment: @IvanRubinson I fail to see how this would help there, though. If the function accepts `T&`, it probably modifies its argument (otherwise it could accept `const T &`). Which means it would fail again for prvalues.

Answer (score 6):

The literal answer is probably because literals predate the addition of `const` to the language, so naturally they are not `const`.

But the practical answer is - `const` prvalues are fundamentally strange things. You cannot create them from any of the fundamental types, but you can have a `const` prvalue of class type. But... why? Typically, we make things `const` to prevent further modifications right. But if it's a prvalue, it's not even a thing with identity - who is going to be there to observe its unintended modification? `const` prvalues prevent moving - because they're `const`, so you can't move from them, so its a premature pessimization.

Note that the one thing that *could* go wrong, that a hypothetical `const` literal would prevent, is already explicitly forbidden by the language:

```
void foo(int&);
foo(42); // error
```

But rather than making `42` `const`, the language made lvalue references non-`const` not allowed to bind to rvalues.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that by default C++ is *pass by **value***, meaning values are *copied*.

There's no way to modify a numeric literal value like 42, because all you have is a copy in a variable. The literal value itself doesn't even have to be stored in memory, the compiler could use it directly in the generated code.

Comment: "There's no way to modify a numeric literal value" - So why isn't it `const`?

Comment: @IvanRubinson Because you can't do `42 = 5`? There's simply no need to make numeric literals constant since they by their very nature already are. Once you store a numeric literal in a variable, you have a ***copy*** of the numeric literal, a copy that you can modify as much as you want, because it's no longer the original literal value.

Comment: "There's no need to make numeric literals constant since they by their very nature already are" - That smells fishy. If it's `const` by its very nature, why isn't it `const`?

Comment: @IvanRubinson It seems you're not listening. For the last time, once you put a numeric literal value into a variable, it is the *variable* you work with, not the literal itself! A numeric literal is a [*prvalue*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue), they can *never* be on the left side of an assignment. You can't get the address of (pointer to) a numeric literal, there is no way in the language to modify one.

Comment: Literals have a type. An int literal has the type of int. If the literal can't be modified, why isn't its type const int (in addition to being a prvalue)?

Comment: @IvanRubinson - Because being a **pure rvalue** is enough. It's not an object, it's just a (nebulous) value that can be used to create an object.